# How to disable navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, childviewcontroller

I would like to disable the navigation bar while adding a child view and enable it again once I remove the child view. How to do that. A similar action when an action sheet is shown.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note, that you may have to keep track of what buttons were initially disabled, if you want to avoid enabling them again this way.

I also haven't checked if this includes the back button. I'm guessing it doesn't, so you'll have to account for this if needed too.

```
NSArray* allBarButtons = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItems arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems];
for (UIBarButtonItem* barButton in allBarButtons) {
     barButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use (Objective-C):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: I need to disable and give it a faded look just like the ActionSheet does.

Comment: set the alpha value of the navigation bar to some 0.6 or 0.5 for fading and when wanted normal, reset it to 1.  navigationBar.alpha=0.5f;

Comment: That works but the status bar is now fading out in iOS7

Comment: That is unexpected. because the statusbar will be having an alpha 1. you may try changing the statusbar type lightcontent. if still the problem persists, am sorry bro.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 4**, place the code below inside `viewDidLoad()` of your ViewController.

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];